# Find the cumulative distribution and density of Y = |U − V |

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $U, V$ be random numbers chosen independently from the interval [0,1] with uniform distribution. Find the cumulative distribution and density of $Y = |U − V |$

The answer is $F(y) = 2y − y^2$ and

$f(y) = 2 − 2y$,

for $0 ≤ y ≤ 1$

but I'm not sure how they arrived to this point. I know $F(y)$ is the area (probability) and $f(x)$ is the derivative of $F(x)$.

Comment: Hint: Geometrically speaking, for every $y$ in $(0,1)$, what is the region in the $(u,v)$-unit square defined by the inequality $|u-v|\geqslant y$? Thus, its area is...

Comment: @Did It would be the line v=u because then that would make y=0.

Comment: No. You fix some $y$. Then you try to picture the region $|u-v|\geqslant y$. Of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few errors in Hasan Heydari's answer, but it's on the right lines.

The cdf of $|U-V|$ is $$P(V-U\in[-y,\,y])=P(V\in[U-y,\,U+y])=\int_0^1  P(V\in[u-y,\,u+y])du.$$ To compute the integral, we'll consider the area under the graph with some basic geometry.

Consider first the case $y\le \frac{1}{2}$. The integrand is $u+y$ if $u<y$ , $2y$ for $y\le u\le 1-y$ and $1-u+y$ if $u>1-y$.  The graph is the sum of two areas. The first is a rectangle of area $y\cdot 1 =y$. The other is a trapezium above said rectangle, of height $y$ and parallel sides of width $1,\,1-2y$, so its area is $y-y^2$. Summing these gives $2y-y^2$ as required. Note this is $1-(1-y)^2$, which is invariant under the transformation $y\mapsto 1-y$ that recovers the $y>\frac{1}{2}$ case.

I'll leave a visualisation of the geometry for $y>\frac{1}{2}$, but there's another way to prove the cdf is $y\mapsto 1-y$=invariant: the distributions of $U,\,V$ are too. Such a transformation changes the sign of $U-V$, i.e. leaves $|U-V|$ unchanged.

Comment: Why are we considering $y /leq 1/2$?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
F_{Y}(y) 
  &= P(Y\leq y)
\\&= P(|U-V|\leq y)
\\&= P\Big((-y \leq U-V) \land (U-V\leq y)\Big)
\\&= P\Big((V-U \leq y) \land (U-V\leq y)\Big)
\end{align}

We know $V,U \in[0,1]$, $P(V=U) = 0$, and $y\in[0,1]$.

- Suppose $U-V$ be a positive number, then $V-U$ is a negative number and $V-U\leq y$ is true.
- Suppose $U-V$ be a negative number, then $U-V\leq y$ is true.

Thus, one of $V-U$ or $U-V$ is always true. We also know $P(V-U \leq y) = P(U-V \leq y)$. Therefore, we need only to compute $P(V-U \leq y)$.

\begin{align}
F_{Y}(y) 
  &= P(Y\leq y)
\\&= P(V-U \leq y)
\\&= P(V \leq y + U)
\\& = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y+u}1\times1 dvdu
\\& = \int_{0}^{1}(y+u)du
\\& = y + \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}